# Is it possible to overload object function properties in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to know if there is a simple way of overloading function property of an object in typescript. Example:

```
interface Doable {
    do(s: number): number;
    do(s: string): string;
}

let obj: Doable = {
    do(s: number): number;
    do(s: string): string;
    do(s: number | string) {
        return s;
    }
}
```

The compiler here will raise an error complaining that `do` property is duplicate.

A potential solution can be

```
let obj = {
    do(s: any): any {
        return s;
    }
};
```

However, I don't like that I'm using the `any` type for the `s` parameter. Is there a way of declaring the function without using `any`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you need to do this without relying on an interface, you can accomplish this by overloading a function in the scope of the object literal and then setting it on the literal.

example:

```
function myFunc(a : number) : number;
function myFunc(b : string, c : string) : boolean;
function myFunc(a : number | string, c? : string) : any{
  //function impl goes here
}

const myLiteral = {
   myFunc
};
```

This way you don't have to use any, and you can use functions with differing numbers of parameters. (The function definition returning any in my example is not used as one of the valid function signatures; only the first two definitions before the impl are.)

Got the idea from: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html (scroll to the bottom)

Comment: wuoh! some juicy extra awesomeness in this answer!

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. The accepted answer doesn't work with non-any return type.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to declare the overload signatures in the object literal. Just write:

```
interface Doable {
    do(s: number): number;
    do(s: string): string;
}

let obj: Doable = {
    do(s: number | string): any {
        return 42;
        return '';
    }
}

obj(42); obj(''); // OK
```

The return value checking part of this is a little weird since technically TypeScript wants you to return `number & string` which isn't a thing that actually happens, so using `any` as the return type is the simplest way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: this is incorrect for overloads that have differing number of parameters. also true overloading returns the correct type depending on which signature is matched as opposed to any which loses all type safety

Comment: i stand corrected, though your example didn't show it, this works perfectly well with differing numbers of parameters, and the any isn't shown when using the object. my bad for making an assumption, i read too quickly and assumed you just suggested raw union types.

Comment: Hey @Ryan Cavanaugh is there a github issue with a feature request to be able to define it the same way author defines, but without interface declaration? Obviously its not convenient to define a separate interface for the same object, especially when it gets larger

Comment: @pleerock see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45049076/980860

Answer (score 7):

You can combine the best of two worlds from other answers:

- [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) / [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) abstraction for *caller* side
- [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) for *callee* side, to annotate strong return types (not [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any)) to function body

```
interface Doable {
    foo(s: number): number;
    foo(s: string): string;
}

function fn(s: number): number;
function fn(s: string): string;
function fn(s: string | number): string | number {
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? "foo" : 42
    // strong types for callee / function body:
    // e.g. `return true` causes error, as not assignable to string | number
}

let obj: Doable = { foo: fn }

// strong types for caller / consumer
obj.foo(42) // number
obj.foo("foo") // string
// obj.do(true) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHs4CMA2KDeAsAFDJnIzroAUAzgFzIgCuAtltAJSMvvQDcJchSp1GtMFFABzbsglSQ0wcQC+JEjGYgEYYOhAUQYpmw5Q5vcyq069BoyYUy5zpTe279hmMYbzJGWQAH1M+C3FApRCw82QiUnIoCDBmKEMAWTgwAAsAOig4EAATdFZqTmQAPmQABjyAVmQAfmQAIkp0NuRGABYAJiFyAHphgKgDaWQwAE8ABwhaEShkBDgcPBQx2y8HLHRimfohslHkCDzpPOQAA2TU9OmoZggb1bhmWkXzqAmoABpkHAliB0GAgbRaMBpCBsHhpuhxkFQlZoCR1MQSHhwegsAArRgYOEoAC88RE6EYvmQGJIZwUk2m82+lBWaw20GQYwQBlobDRxFxeLynWoA0qZ1RUBIQpFog6VDaErGbmkdLGstK1EkL2VPz+JCAA)

Answer (score 5):

In fact, it *is* possible to put this on the object directly! The syntax is a bit clumsy, but it works:

```js
let myLiteral = {
  myFunc: ((a : number | string, c? : string) => {
    // implementation goes here
  }) as {
    // overloads go here
    (a : number): number;
    (b : string, c : string): boolean;
  }
};
```

Comment: this is a clever solution. However, what I don't like about it is that it feels kinda more difficult to read. But anyways, it's a good thing to have multiple solutions to the same problem, so +1 from me :)

Comment: Just be aware that this rids you of type inference for `this` within `myFunc`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a neat trick to implement this when using a ***.d.ts** or **types.d.ts** file to define the object literal.

Suppose you wanted your object function to have the following structures

```js
myFunc(arg1: number, arg2: string): void;
myFunc(arg1: number, arg2: string, arg3: Boolean): void;
```

First, in your object literal **type** or **interface**, define the object property as an object containing the different structures of your function.

```js
// *.d.ts
type MyObjType = {
 ...,
 myPropFunc: {
  (arg1: number, arg2: string): void;
  (arg1: number, arg2: string, arg3: Boolean): void;
 }
}
```

Then, simply create your overloaded function as you normally would:

```js
// *.ts file
function myFunc(arg1: number, arg2 : string): void;
function myFunc(arg1: number, arg2 : string, arg3: Boolean): void;
function myFunc(arg1: number, arg2 : string, arg3?: Boolean): void {
  ...
}

const myLiteral: MyObjType = {
   myFunc
};
```