# Typescript function overloading in `interface`

Tags: typescript, overloading

I'm working for the first time with overloads in Typescript, and ran into some errors with defining them within an `interface`.

I think I'm understanding the concept properly, because these examples compile without error:

```js
function test(): void;
function test(str: string): string;

// OK
function test(str?: string) {
    if (typeof str === 'string') return str;
};

test(); // OK
test(''); // OK
```

```js
class Test2 {
    public test(): void;
    public test(str: string): string;

    // OK
    public test(str?: string) {
        if (typeof str === 'string') return str;
    }

    constructor() {
        this.test(); // OK
        this.test(''); // OK
    }
}
```

However, these all throw either:

- `Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '{ (): void; (str: string): string; }'.`
- `Type '(str: string) => string' is not assignable to type '{ (): void; (str: string): string; }'.`

```js
interface Test {
    test(): void;
    test(str: string): string;
}

const test1: Test = {
    test: () => {}, // ERROR
};

const test2: Test = {
    test: (str: string) => str, // ERROR
};

class Test implements Test {
    constructor() {
        this.test = () => {}; // ERROR
        this.test = (str: string) => ''; // ERROR
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Typescript?

EDIT: Here's the code in the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitReturns=false&ssl=52&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/PQKhCgAIUgzBDAlgG0QOwOYBpJoPYAukAzgK4BOAppAO4AWAnlCMOOOgZeQgMbUAqlYkQDeUSBM7CAFAEoAXJABueRABMA3OMlCC04eUUH0GBSQLkTWgL5seeNMMhSCARkWCnAXkhiJO4UU5SC8APl9Iayxway1we0ciFwAmD10Q321nXSCDIwsTWRDwg2jYu2R4YmJITyJEAFsAB2RKBso0Ahq6zP9IBINSHgI8cmC-Pv8COkRiADoXDOCwiPLJqZn5xZ99C3zLTCKVgHJjrT7bW3BQCGhaUYBrE0gqyEoADybKYco1ZlZwLBSGhhogHNkZGYVOotECQQQwWgIXo8uYDqZ9lY2HDQeCXLtyAB+TGHXr+RCwSDSAgML54SkGEJeHzHYyYY5FKgEChIgw2OL42RafGnIUVKrdXTJMkSJqkABGqB4yLkimhmiycsViGV+NRbIxaKxmoVSpVBmJRtJE3WFKpNLpDIsTJZBo5kC5PLR538Vz6AwsQxGYyKNsm01mC10ch96xFHNjkRi4CAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your failing cases are failing because, on every occasion, you assign an implementation that only satisfies one of the overloaded function signatures defined in the interface.

This would be hard to do, as you can't define two properties with the same name on any given object. So, just as was the case for your `function` declaration, you need to provide one implementation that satisfies both function signatures:

```
interface Test {
    test(): void;
    test(str: string): string;
}

const test: Test = {
    test: (str?: string): any => {
        if (typeof str === 'string') return str;
    }
};

class Test implements Test {
    constructor() {
        this.test = (str?: string): any => {
            if (typeof str === 'string') return str;
        }
    }
}
```

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34799303/3558960), specifying a return type that matches both `void` and `string` is non-trivial (not possible?), so need to use `any`.