# TypeScript method overloading

Tags: typescript, overloading, typescript-typings

This question is about method overloading in TypeScript. I can define the interface `Api` without any problems. However if I implement it I get the error blow. I check which signature is called by checking the type of `arg` and return the right type accordingly. However the code does not compile. Unfortunately I can't find anything about overloading in the official TS docs.

```js
interface Api {
  test(arg: string): string;
  test(arg: number): string[];
}

const api: Api = {
  test(arg: string | number) {
    if (typeof arg === "string") {
      return "string";
    }
    return ["string", "string"];
  },
};
```

```
Type '(arg: string | number) => string[] | "string"' is not assignable to type '{ (arg: string): string; (arg: number): string[]; }'.
  Type 'string[] | "string"' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're trying to do in TS tbh. You're doing it "right" but it doesn't work when declaring an instance of an interface... you could do this when declaring a class that implements the API interface, but not a const

Comment: Is there a technical reason for this or does the language just not support it?

Comment: well, the issue that I can see is that for the function declaration to match the interface, you need to decorate the implementation with all of the overload signatures (as in, if you were doing this in a class implementation). But you can't do that in an instance / const declaration, so TS says it doesn't match the interface, and I don't see a way to make it match, so this seems like a limitation of the language, given how it matches overload interfaces with their implementation.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thank you for the explantation.

Comment: Actually might be worth opening an issue about this on the repo. I think if the implementing class or object covers all the overloaded signatures, that should be fine.

Comment: @Elias I wouldn't be sure if they are willing to add overloading in objects. An object is a living instance of a class, and since you can define overloads on classes and their methods it shouldn't be possible to do so on objects as that would suggest you can change the type definition of an already initialized class.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately as pointed out in the comments it is not possible to overload functions when declaring them in objects.
What you can do - if you're willing to sacrifice on some convenience - is to declare your `test` function outside the object along with all the overload signatures and then assign it to that object.

```
function test(arg: string): string;
function test(arg: number): string[];
function test(arg: number|string) : string|string[] {
    if (typeof arg === "string") {
        return "string";
    }
    return ["string", "string"];
}
```

After the `test` function has been declared you can create a new object that implements the `Api` interface and assign your function to it.

```
interface Api {
    test(arg: string): string;
    test(arg: number): string[];
}

const api: Api = { test }
```

This is not entirely an amazing way to achieve what you want as any changes to the interface or the function declaration would also mean you'll have to change the other one as well.

There are some other answers from people way smarter than me under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798989/is-it-possible-to-overload-object-function-properties-in-typescript/45049076#45049076).
I know it's late, but better late than ever.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using classes, this works:

```js
interface Api {
  test(arg: string): string;
  test(arg: number): string[];
}

class WhateverApi implements Api {
  test(arg: string): string;
  test(arg: number): string[];
  test(arg: string | number): string | string[] {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
}
```

It was mentioned in the comments, that this means you will need to add (and potentially expose) an extra class. Technically, you could use an anonymous class to fix that:

```js
const api = new class implements Api {
  test(arg: string): string;
  test(arg: number): string[];
  test(arg: string | number): string | string[] {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
};
```

Comment: That's also a good way of working this out, but one small catch would be that you'd either have to expose that class to the outside world already initialized or use static methods.

Comment: Sure, you would then need to call `const api = new WhateverApi()`. You could technically use an anonymous class, I'll edit my answer and add that, lol.